creating a new file with the extension ".mcfunction" always adds ".m" at the end, making "file.mcfunction.m"
I disabled all my extensions, and even reset VSCode to factory settings, yet nothing worked.
It does appear to have a certain icon associated with it. I believe it is for the language objective-C, which I do not use.
I created a new file, named it "file.mcfunction", and after it is created, it is now called "file.mcfunction.m"
How do i disable this behaviour?
steps to reproduce .png

Show how exactly you save the file and choose the filename.

Which version and OS are you using?
